# Show "Keep Typing" in react-select search till the number of queries/letters exceeds 2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select, country, react-select-search

I am working on country search in `react-select`.I am using react `SortableSelect` (almost similar to select). I want to show "Keep Typing" box beneath the select box when i click on the box till the number of letters exceeds 2.

By the letters that i have entered it should show the appropriate country options , just like searching country.

```
 <SortableSelect
        onSortEnd={onSortEnd}
        distance={4}
        isMulti
        options={countryOptions}
        value={destinations}
        onChange={handleChipDestinations}
        components={{
           MultiValue: SortableMultiValue,
            }}
        closeMenuOnSelect={false}
        placeholder="Search Country"
    />
```